# Choosing Ubuntu over WSL for Plutus development

Tags: plutus, plutus-playground, ubuntu

I use a low end laptop as my daily driver running a `WSL Ubuntu-20.04` as my platform of choice. When trying to run the `plutus-playground` it often crashes. Should I try using Ubuntu or any other Linux boot for the development or will I get a similar experience there too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WSL is a hack for running Linux programs. Plutus Playground is very stable once it is installed on a stable platform. I had hosted a playground without any issue for more than a month that too without restart. It is highly recommended that Ubuntu or other Linux OS be used as a base platform than Windows.

Comment: Ubuntu is far better, just tried running plutus on it :chef_kiss:.